# invalid pure specifier (only '= 0' is allowed) before 'int'

Tags: arduino-uno, programming

```
#include <PixySPI_SS.h>
#include <Pixy.h>
#include <Adafruit_MotorShield.h>
#define X_CENTER        ((PIXY_MAX_X-PIXY_MIN_X)/2)       
#define Y_CENTER        ((PIXY_MAX_Y-PIXY_MIN_Y)/2)

Pixy pixy;
 int TrackedBlock(int n) = 
{
 int trackedBlock=0;
 float maxSize=0; 
  for (int k=0;k<n;k++)
  {
    float newSize= pixy.blocks[k].height * pixy.blocks[k].width;
    if (newSize>maxSize)
    {
      maxSize=newSize;
      trackedBlock=k;
    }

  }
   return trackedBlock
}
```

For some reason the code returns the error message in the title every time I try to compile it. I can't really find any issues online that's the same as my error. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What happens if you remove the "=" from this "int TrackedBlock(int n) = " and add a ";" at the end of this "return trackedBlock"?

Comment: yeah, because `int TrackedBlock(int n) = ` is not how you write a function in C

Comment: Look, this isn't a forum. Please post your answer using the "answer" box. Then it can be accepted. The only answer here right now is a "thanks" for your comment. This is totally subverting how Stack Exchange is supposed to work.